# load content to div jquery

Tags: jquery, html, load

I load a content to div using simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //   INITIAL
"use strict";   $('#box-03').load('EXTREL_CONTENT/2up.php');
    //   Handle menu clicks
$('ul#main-menu li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#box-03').load('EXTREL_CONTENT/' + page + '.php');
    return false;
});
});
```

and it works well for me. Is it possible to load the same content to div (fe. #box-4) located on another page (different php file) - "let's say: one level higher"?
Many thanks in advance for your response.
Best.

Comment: yes, I know. I complicate my life by myself :-).

Comment: You can embed the same JS code in that second PHP file.

Comment: JS cannot find div located on second php page...doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work by adding "`../`" to the beginning of the `php` file path:

```
$('#box-04').load('../EXTREL_CONTENT/' + page + '.php');
```

Comment: Ok. This I know. But what if my div #box-4 is located on another page? What about the string $('#box-4)?

Comment: My code is located on 1.php page and loads content to div#box-3 creating subpage, let's say 1a.php, where the next menu is placed. By clicking one of the button on the "sub-menu" I would like to load the content to div#box-3 again. Let's keep the div id=box-03.

Comment: I've resolved my problem. Partially thanks to Dreamweaver's behaviour funtions. But it works well and it's good enough for me. Thanks.